# Hiding DataGrid column except the header in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I was able to hide my unwanted column and rows in my DataGrid using OnItemDataBound

```
 e.Item.Cells(0).Visible = False
```

but the problem is the Headers are also disappearing. How can i hide the rows only and remain its header visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check  the [`DataGridItem.ItemType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagriditem.itemtype(v=vs.110).aspx) and only apply the code if it's `Item` or `AlternatingItem` to skip the `Header`:

```
Sub Item_Bound(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs) 
      If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse _
            e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        e.Item.Cells(0).Visible = False
     End If         
End Sub
```

As an aside, if you loop all `Items` in the grid all other `ItemType`s are skipped automatically.

```
For Each item As DataGridItem In dataGrid1.Items
    ' Here only Item/AlternatingItem items are available,  others are omitted by default.
Next
```

Comment: whoa, been searchin answers for days, i didn't know i can do it like this. thank you @Tim!.

Comment: @dale: note that i've edited my answer to mention that the header,footer are only passed to `ItemCreated` or `ItemDataBound`, if you loop the `Items`-property those are omitted by default.